# What does high impedance value mean?

Tags: transistors

I'm taking a look right now at page 215 of *Verilog HDL: A Guide to Digital Design and Synthesis* by Samir Palnitkar, where it's talking about Verilog primitives to represent MOSFETs. It says, "Thus, the nmos switch conducts when its control signal is 1. If control signal is 0, the output assumes a high impedance value." What does that mean, "a high impedance value"?

Comment: High impedance is similar to high resistance, except that the exact value might change with frequency (usually decreases with increasing frequency in this context).

Answer (score 3):

In this context, it means that the digital signal line is not being **actively driven** to either a 0 or a 1. When a signal is in a high-impedance state, another driver (i.e. another gate output) can control the logic level of the signal.

This is a common way to allow multiple drivers to share the same data line. There is some control logic that determines which driver is allowed to put data on the line, and all other drivers must be in the high-impedance state.

If you are writing behavioral Verilog, you can assign the value `Z` to a signal to put it in the high-impedance state. Likewise, a simulator should show the value `Z` for a high-impedance signal.

Comment: Answer should include the Verilog value to expect/use for "high impedance".

Answer (score 2):

> It says, "Thus, the nmos switch conducts when its control signal is 1. If control signal is 0, the output assumes a high impedance value."

A very basic demonstration of typical device output is shown below. The MOSFETs are represented by switches.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2RLzi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Three possible output conditions.*

The device represented by Figure 1 can pull active high, active low or high impedance. The switches represent the low on-resistance of the output stage transistors. Note that the condition of both on simultaneously is to be avoided as "shoot-through" - a high current due to the low resistance between V+ and GND - and this could burn out the output stage.

---

[image]

*Figure 11.1 from the Verilog reference.*

Page 214 of the document shows that in this case there is a simple disconnect between the previous logic and the output. In the case of the NMOS having a '1' on the control pin the data is available on the 'out' pin. That means that the out pin will be driven high or low depending on the data value. If the control is '0' then out is disconnected from data and is free to be pulled high or low by some other output (assuming multiple outputs appear on the line).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbHWSK.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. The control signal is represented by the relay contact, SW3.*

> What does that mean, "a high impedance value"?

It should be clear from Figure 3 that very little current - only leakage current - could be drawn from the output and so it appears as a very high resistance or impedance (when dealing with time-varying signals). Effectively it's not connected to anything.

Answer (score 0):

> An NMOS FET like all discrete semi. switches are inverting logic levels from in to out and low resistance when "ON" and high resistance when OFF.  (The mechanical equivalent is a SPST-NO relay)

Impedance , Z(f) is defined with resistance + X(f) reactance,  created by either capacitance or inductance. When that portion is negligible then  **Impedance = Resistance.**

"High Z" is a relative term but for FET gates, might be considered to be > 10 Megohms.

When paired with a complementary PFET , we call it CMOS.

We sometimes call them "open-drain switches" or when NPN transistors called "open collector " switches.

### Other info

for "Impedance" , I digress...

For an ideal capacitor Ic= C  ΔV/ Δt *(  ΔV/Δt is the slew rate of voltage. )*

If we consider resistance, R from Ohm's Law is R= ΔV/ΔI or just V/I, you can imagine the impedance of small capacitance depends on the rate of change of voltage such that ...

Zc=  ΔV/ΔI =  Δt/C  but depending on the thresholds used for these  Δ's this is just a visualization. The more accurate estimate is Zc(f)=Δt/(0.35*2π)C  which is never used.

Also  Z(f) when f=0 it is just DC resistance ... until a transition occurs.